# How to graph inc exponential decay in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, graph, formula, exponential

My prof decided that our first experience with coding was going to be trying to fit the function z(t) = A(1-e^(-t/T)) into a given data-set from class using R. I'm completely lost. I keep using `lm` and `nls` functions, without quite knowing how they work. So far, I have the data graphed but I have no clue how to get any sort of line more complicated than

```
mod3<-lm(y~I(x^1/5))
pre3<-predict(mod3)
lines(pre3)
```

to sum up: how do I find the A and T parameters? Do I use `nls` for the formula? Anything helps. I'll include a picture of the graph and the data. Please ignore the random lines on the plot. [graph depicting my dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhnyO.png) [dataset I have to use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYVFZ.png)

Comment: lm is used when the right hand side is linear in the coefficients. The right hand side here is linear in A but not in T so  use nls.  If T were fixed at a known value as opposed to estimating it from the data then you could use lm.

Answer (score 0):

One could attempt transform your expression into a linear relationship, but sometimes it is easier to just let the computer do the work.  As mention in the comments, R has the `nls` function to perform the nonlinear regression.

Here is an example using some dummy data.  The supply the `nls` function with your equation, the data frame containing the data and supply it with the initial estimates of the parameters.

See comments for additional details.

```
#create dummy data
A= 0.8
T1 = 13

t <- seq(2, 50, 3)
z <- A*(1-exp(-t/T1)) 
z<- z +rnorm(length(z), 0, 0.005) #add noise

#starting data frame
df <-data.frame(t, z)

#solve non-linear model
model <- nls(z ~ A*(1-exp(-t/Tc)), data=df, start = list(A=1, Tc=1))
print(summary(model))
#predict
pred_y <-predict(model, data.frame(t))

#plot
plot(x=t, y=z)
lines(y=pred_y, x= t, col="blue")
```